# How do I test SSL on a developer machine?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I don't want to buy an SSL certificate yet, but still want to test SSL on my development server.

Is there a way to generate a temporary certificate, for testing purposes, albeit with warnings from browsers upon page load?

Comment: There have got to be a million tutorials on this subject out there. Did you look?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can generate a self sign certificate and install it on your web server. If you are using apache, then you can use `openssl` to generate a self-signed certificate. If you care using Java, then you can use `keytool` to generate a self-signed certificate. If you are using .NET, then you can use `makecert`.

Comment: Would be better if you showed examples.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/certificates.txt

Answer (score 1):

Yes download TinyCA or similar and create your own self signed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate [self-signed test certs](http://code.google.com/apis/apps/articles/sso-keygen.html) using OpenSSL, .NET or Java tools.